# Import FormsModule in shared.module.ts - Angular 16

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular15, angular16

I am trying to import the FormsModule and the ReactiveFormsModule into my shared.module.ts file. This is the code:

```
imports: [
  CommonModule,
  MaterialModule,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
],
```

This is the error

```
Value at position 2 in the NgModule.imports of SharedModule is not a reference
  Value could not be determined statically.(-991010)
```

Comment: How do you define `MaterialModule` ?

Comment: @Wandrille import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module'; and it is basically an extra Angular module without routing where I import all Material components.